# Structure Map and Aspnet.Identity UserManager static class issue

Tags: c#, static, asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I've got an issue with getting correct instance of UserManager in my Account Controller. Currently, I cannot get password reset to work as my provider and other settings are being ignored.

In Startup - void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) I've got following:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ViewingBookerDatabaseContext>(ViewingBookerDatabaseContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

Then in AccountManager class, method Create referenced above contains following:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    // Configure the application user manager
    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new ViewingBookerDatabaseContext()));

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
```

Now, this worked great before I installed IoC - in this case StrcutureMap. IoC for controllers is registered in following pattern:

```
Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
        });

public class ControllerConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (type.CanBeCastTo(typeof(Controller)) && !type.IsAbstract)
        {
            registry.For(type).LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle());
        }
    }
}
```

UserManager is then referenced in my AccountController as follows:

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    public AccountController() 
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ViewingBookerDatabaseContext context, CurrentUser currentUser, Logger logger, EmailService emailService)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
        _currentUser = currentUser;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailService = emailService;
    }
```

Now, UserManager is being used for my password reset, account creation etc. After installing IoC, I get "No ITokenProvider is registered" for password reset, account names with @ are being returned as invalid when creating user etc. Looks like AccountController's instance of ApplicationUserManager is not created via Create() method of ApplicationUserManager class.

Can anyone point me to a correct implementation of strucutre map, so it calls Create to get an instance of AccountUserManager rather than returning a generic instance of that class that contains no ITokenProvider spec. etc?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys. Since nobody replied for so long, had to do some further research and come up with following, probably not the most elegant, tho a working solution:

**1. Startup.cs - remove following lines**

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ViewingBookerDatabaseContext>   (ViewingBookerDatabaseContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

**2. Introduce new variable in Startup.cs**

*public static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }*

then, set it in public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) to following:

*DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();*

**3. ApplicationUserManager or whatever you call it, remove static Create method and change its constructor to following:**

```
         public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store)
        : base(store)
    {
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
    }
```

For password reset ITokenProvider, simply reference Startup's DataProtectionProvider variable like this:

```
    if (Startup.DataProtectionProvider != null)
            UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(Startup.DataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

**And finally...**

in AccountController.cs - remove any reference to the getter of ApplicationUserManager and reuse the instance that is supplied in controller's constructor by StructureMap.

```
 public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
```

so you'll be calling _userManager object methods instead

```
   REMOVE IF YOU HAVE IT IN YOUR CONTROLLER:
   public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ??    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Except my login/register buttons don't work at all. I tried the solution you described and I think it's the right direction, but I still get the same error.. `No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IUserStore<ApplicationUser>'` Also I get a warning that ApplicationUserManager is never instantiated, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Still trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can register creation callbacks to set these properties outside of the static create. Here's how I accomplished the same thing:

```
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create, (options, manager) =>
        {
            options.DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(options.DataProtectionProvider.Create("AspNet.com"));
        });
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```